# OSX bash terminal auto-completion - odd behavior on double tab

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I am on OSX Sierra 10.12.6 and I am experiencing odd behavior in terminal windows.

When entering a command like `cd ~/`, I expect to press Tab twice quickly to see all path options. For example:

```
cd ~/

[double press tab]

cd ~/
.CFUserTextEncoding
.DS_Store
.Trash/
.account
.android/
.avn/
.avnrc
.babel.json
.bash_history
.bash_profile
...
```

Instead, I only see one path option at a time. Pressing Tab simply cycles to the next one:

```
cd ~/
[press tab]
cd ~/.CFUserTextEncoding
[press tab]
cd ~/.DS_Store
[press tab]
cd ~/.Trash/
...etc
```

Pressing Tab twice quickly simply does this twice.

This issue has remained constant through multiple OS updates. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have `menu-complete`, not `complete`, bound to the tab key. (Confirm with `bind -P | grep menu-complete`.) There are several ways this could have been activated:

- `C-i: menu-complete` in your `.inputrc` file
- `bind 'C-i: menu-complete'` in `.bashrc` or some other shell configuration file.

If you can find the offending line, remove it to restore the default binding to `complete`. If you can't, try adding `C-i: complete` to your `.inputrc` file to override the binding to `menu-complete`.

Comment: Amazing! This has been driving me insane for months. Thank you!

Comment: Followed by a Great Answer.